# Split parsed rss results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rss

I'm working on a project to parse RSS feeds from several sites into an aggregated job board, using [rss-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-parser)

The feeds use different formats for `title`, and as such the parsed JSON has differing formats too. See sample of three different formats below.

```
title: Roundtrip: Senior Product Designer
title: Frontend Developer
title: Unreal is looking for a Product Designer
```

What I'm looking to do is to unify the title / company format

- Split `Roundtrip: Senior Product Designer` into `company: Roundtrip` and `title: Senior Product Designer`
- Split `Unreal is looking for a Product Designer` into `company: Unreal` and `title: Product Designer`.

Currently they're merged to an array in the state using

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
      data: this.state.data.concat(feed.items)
    }));
```

But this puts me in the position where the differing title formats become very apparent.

**How would I go about splitting those strings and *then* merging them to a combined array?**

Comment: '"is looking for a "...is this string constant in all titles for the third format..or can it change ?

Comment: It's almost a constant, which I guess makes it not a constant. The only difference is that sometimes it's "is looking for *a*" and sometimes "is looking for *an*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a map over the items to get a new array with title and company keys.

```
let items = [{title:'Roundtrip: Senior Product Designer'},{title:'Frontend Developer'},{title:'Unreal is looking for a Product Designer'}]

console.log(items.map(item => {
const colonSeperated = item.title.split(':')
const phraseSeperated = item.title.split('is looking for ')
  if(colonSeperated.length == 2){
   return ({
     company:colonSeperated[0],
     title: colonSeperated[1].trim(' ')
   })
   }
 else if(phraseSeperated.length ==2){
    const phraseSeperatedTitle = 
       phraseSeperated[1].startsWith('an')? 
       phraseSeperated[1].substr(2):phraseSeperated[1].substr(1)
   return({
    company:phraseSeperated[0].trim(' '),
    title: phraseSeperatedTitle.trim(' ')
  })
}
else {
  return ({
    company:null,
    title:item.title 

   })
  }
  }
))
```

Comment: This is fantastic. How would I get this to take into account whether the format says "is looking for **a**" or "is looking for **an**"

Comment: Edited the code to add a condition based upon the starting of the string after 'is looking for'.I think this should do it.Please upvote if the answer helped you :)

Comment: You could accept,upvote and close this if my approach worked for you.